Customise the Kubernetes ConfigMap of an ingress controller cloud deployment
I have a Kubernetes cluster hosting a number of web apps which until now has got by using the default nginx ingress controller provided on Github.
This I've been deploying from an Azure DevOps pipeline using this simple YAML task:
        - task: Kubernetes@1
          displayName: 'Deploy Ingress controller'
          inputs:
            connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
            azureSubscriptionEndpoint: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
            azureResourceGroup: ${{ variables.resourcePrefix }}-rg
            kubernetesCluster: ${{ variables.resourcePrefix }}-cluster
            command: 'apply'
            arguments: '-f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-${{ parameters.nginxControllerVersion }}/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml'
            secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
            containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'

However, I have now encountered a case where I need to change the proxy-buffer-size property in the ConfigMap (i.e. extend the default ConfigMap here).
The ConfigMap created by the above apply command looks like this:
Name:         ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:    ingress-nginx
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/version=1.10.0
              k8slens-edit-resource-version=v1
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
allow-snippet-annotations:
----
false

I'm relatively new to Kubernetes so I'm looking for advice about the simplest way to extend  this config map. Having done some reading it seems kustomize may be the way to go. From what I can tell this is a way to merge changes into an existing Kubernetes object. But I just cannot get started with this. Here's what I've tried:
Add a kustomization.yaml file to a directory kustomize/nginx:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

configMapGenerator:
- name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  behavior: merge
  literals:
  - test=value

Run kubectl apply -k ./kustomize/nginx
Error is:

error: merging from generator &{0xc000b67ba0 }: id resid.ResId{Gvk:resid.Gvk{Group:"", Version:"v1", Kind:"ConfigMap", isClusterScoped:false}, Name:"ingress-nginx-controller", Namespace:"ingress-nginx"} does not exist; cannot merge or replace

I have no idea what this means or how to solve it. Am I heading down the right path here? If so, what am I missing? If not, which direction should I be headed to achieve what feels like it should be a very simple change? Thanks.

I found the answer. Kustomize needs to know which resource(s) it is kustomizing.  I needed to add the following section to my kustomization.yaml file:
resources:
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.10.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

After this the command kubectl apply -k .\kubernetes\kustomize\nginx successfully applies my kustomization to the cluster.
